# Prolog - How would I recursively build a list?

Tags: list, prolog, logic, predicate

I'm working through the exercises on [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse12) and I'm stumped on the very last question. Given the following facts:

```
   byCar(auckland,hamilton).
   byCar(hamilton,raglan).
   byCar(valmont,saarbruecken).
   byCar(valmont,metz).
   byTrain(metz,frankfurt).
   byTrain(saarbruecken,frankfurt).
   byTrain(metz,paris).
   byTrain(saarbruecken,paris).
   
   byPlane(frankfurt,bangkok).
   byPlane(frankfurt,singapore).
   byPlane(paris,losAngeles).
   byPlane(bangkok,auckland).
   byPlane(singapore,auckland).
   byPlane(losAngeles,auckland).
```

> Write a predicate travel/2 which determines whether it is possible to travel from one place to another by chaining together car, train,
> and plane journeys. For example, your program should answer yes to the
> query travel(valmont,raglan) .
>
> So, by using travel/2 to query the above database, you can find out
> that it is possible to go from Valmont to Raglan. If you are planning
> such a voyage, that’s already something useful to know, but you would
> probably prefer to have the precise route from Valmont to Raglan.
> Write a predicate travel/3 which tells you which route to take when
> travelling from one place to another. For example, the program should
> respond    X  =  go(valmont,metz,
> go(metz,paris,
> go(paris,losAngeles))) to the query travel(valmont,losAngeles,X) .

here's my go functors:

```
go(X).
go(X,Y).
```

Here's my travel/2 predicate:

```
travel(X,Y) :- byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- byCar(X,Z), travel(Z,Y).

travel(X,Y) :- byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- byTrain(X,Z), travel(Z,Y).

travel(X,Y) :- byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y) :- byPlane(X,Z), travel(Z,Y).
```

However, I'm having trouble with my travel/3 predicate:

```
travel(X,Y,G) :- byCar(X,Y),   G = go(X, Y).
travel(X,Y,G) :- byCar(X,Z),   travel(Z,Y,G).

travel(X,Y,G) :- byTrain(X,Y), G = go(X, Y).       
travel(X,Y,G) :- byTrain(X,Z), travel(Z,Y,G).

travel(X,Y,G) :- byPlane(X,Y), G = go(X, Y).       
travel(X,Y,G) :- byPlane(X,Z), travel(Z,Y,G).
```

When I run the predicate in the question, I get:

```
?- travel(valmont,losAngeles,X).
X = go(paris, losAngeles) .
```

But it's not an entire list like the question needs. I'm not really sure how to accomplish that; whether I need to rewrite my predicates or not. Any help you could offer to help me learn what I'm doing wrong is super appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not changing `G` appropriately in the `travel/3` predicate.

```
travel(X,Y, go(X, Y)) :- byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X, Y)) :- byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X, Y)) :- byPlane(X,Y).

travel(X,Y, go(X, Z, G)) :- byCar(X,Z), travel(Z,Y, G).
travel(X,Y, go(X, Z, G)) :- byTrain(X,Z), travel(Z,Y, G).
travel(X,Y, go(X, Z, G)) :- byPlane(X,Z), travel(Z,Y, G).
```

You get:

```
| ?- travel(valmont, losAngeles, G).
G = go(valmont,saarbruecken,go(saarbruecken,paris,go(paris,losAngeles))) ? ;
G = go(valmont,metz,go(metz,paris,go(paris,losAngeles))) ? ;
no
```

As a bonus you can just embed the type of travel too:

```
travel_(X,Y, car(X, Y)) :- byCar(X,Y).
travel_(X,Y, train(X, Y)) :- byTrain(X,Y).
travel_(X,Y, plane(X, Y)) :- byPlane(X,Y).
      
travel_(X,Y, car(X, Z, G)) :- byCar(X,Z), travel_(Z,Y, G).
travel_(X,Y, train(X, Z, G)) :- byTrain(X,Z), travel_(Z,Y, G).
travel_(X,Y, plane(X, Z, G)) :- byPlane(X,Z), travel_(Z,Y, G).
```

Now you get:

```
| ?- travel_(valmont, losAngeles, G).
G = car(valmont,saarbruecken,train(saarbruecken,paris,plane(paris,losAngeles))) ? ;
G = car(valmont,metz,train(metz,paris,plane(paris,losAngeles))) ? ;
no
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It works now; and your answer helped me understand the next part of the question - showing how (by car, train, or plain) the route is taken. "Changing G" involves specifying what it is in the functor itself so it can unify with the base cases specifically! It makes so much sense now!